# Formatting external USB Harddrive ext4

Tags: ext4

What is the best way to format a non-ssd harddrive with ext4,
for as fast as possible usage with a very low performance computer?

I mean, options like disabling things (journaling, ...) that slow down the process of read/write.

Comment: If you want `ext4` without journaling, then you want `ext2`.

Comment: You don't want to disable the journaling, because if you accidently disconnect the drive while mounted, it'll  take hours to fsck the harddrive to get it usable again. The performance penalty of the journal shouldn't be that big even on a slow CPU. I think default settings should be completely ok.

Comment: Do you have any special requirements that would mandate ext4? If you have some specific usage pattern it might be better to look at other file systems as well.

Comment: I wanted to speed up samba from 5mb/s (because ntfs), now with ext4 I got 12mb/s. I just googled a bit for the mount options in fstab and I disabled atime now, discard this question..